# File menus gone missing

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, menu, window

Since upgrading to:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid*
```

I'm no longer able to open file menu (Edit, View, Search etc) with keyboard shortcut (used to be <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd> etc). The only menu-shortcut that I can find is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for window menu.

I miss my menu shortcuts in my applications and could some one please help me finding them back?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the first menu of the menu bar using <kbd>F10</kbd>, so the first it'll open is the file menu.

You can navigate to other menus using the right and left arrow keys.